# Javascript getting total sum from wrong checkbox trigger

Tags: javascript

Below are two different checkbox and the javascript below seems to be trigger by termsChkbx checkbox instead of chosen. How do I change this portion

```
var chosen = item.parentElement.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]'); ?

echo "\t<div class='item'>
    <span class='CDTitle'>{$CD['CDTitle']}</span>
    <span class='CDYear'>{$CD['CDYear']}</span>
    <span class='catDesc'>{$CD['catDesc']}</span>
    <span class='CDPrice'>{$CD['CDPrice']}</span>
    <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' id='selectChkbx' name='CD[]' value='{$CD['CDID']}' title='{$CD['CDPrice']}' /></span>
    </div>\n";

<p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
<input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx" onchange="isChecked(this,'sub1')"/></p>
```

JS:

```
function createCheckbox(){
    var html = "";
    for(var i = 0; i<5; i++){
        var num = (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2);
        html += "<input type='checkbox' class='chk' value='" +num+ "' onchange='updateTotal()'>" + num + "<br/>";
    }
    document.getElementById("selectChkbx").innerHTML = html;
}

function updateTotal(){
    var chk = document.getElementsByClassName("chk");
    var total = 0;
    console.log(chk);
    for(var i in chk){
        if(chk[i].checked){
            total+=parseFloat(chk[i].value);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}

createCheckbox();
```

Comment: you could give the other checkbox an id or a class and then use `document.getElementById()` or `document.getElementByClass()` or using jquery `$("#id_here")` or `$(".class_here")`

Comment: Do u mean adding in a id to the first checkbox ?

Comment: Yes. Adding an id to the first one, as i see you have done fromedited question

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/0qmn9Lne/)

#### Code

```js
function createCheckbox(){
 var html = "";
    for(var i = 0; i<5; i++){
        var num = (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2);
     html += "<input type='checkbox' class='chk' value='" +num+ "' onchange='updateTotal()'>" + num + "<br/>";
    }
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html;
}

function updateTotal(){
 var chk = document.getElementsByClassName("chk");
    var total = 0;
    console.log(chk);
    for(var i in chk){
     if(chk[i].checked){
         total+=parseFloat(chk[i].value);
        }
    }
    
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
}

createCheckbox();
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<p id="total">0</p>
```

#### Edit 1

I believe reason why you are not getting value is because of element structure. You have a `span` tag which holds price and another `span` tag holds checkbox. For such structure, you will have to navigate to that `span` and fetch its value. Following is depicted below.

#### Fetching Span's value

```
var price = chk[i].parentNode.previousSibling.textContent;
```

#### Code

```js
function createCheckbox(){
 var html = "";
    for(var i = 0; i<5; i++){
        var num = (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2);
        html += "<span>" + num + "</span>";
     html += "<span><input type='checkbox' class='chk' value='" +num+ "' onchange='updateTotal()'>Check</span><br/>";
    }
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html;
}

function updateTotal(){
 var chk = document.getElementsByClassName("chk");
    var total = 0;
    console.log(chk);
    for(var i in chk){
     if(chk[i].checked){
            var price = chk[i].parentNode.previousSibling.textContent;
            total += parseFloat(price);
        }
    }
    
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
}

createCheckbox();
```

```css
.chk{
    
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<p id="total">0</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, i updated the question but it's still not working.. what am i missing

Comment: Take care with `parseFloat()`. You can see weird operations in this snippet. Example: `4.35 + 2.51 + 7.54 = 14.3999999999999999`. It's better in this case to use `Number()` function instead of `parseFloat()`.

Comment: Can you create a sample Fiddle and share it.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not getting weird operations yet. Just that the output is still not showing in total